# CSVHelper 7.1.1 - Header matching [id] names at index 0 was not found

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have an exception thrown when loading this CSV file :/ which is quite simple :

```
 public class BreederTemp
    {
        public BreederTemp ()
        {

        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Affix { get; set; }
        public bool Affix_Prefix { get; set; }
    }

public sealed class BreederClassMap : ClassMap<BreederTemp>
    {
        public BreederClassMap()
        {
            AutoMap();
            Map(m => m.Id);
            Map(m => m.Affix);
            Map(m => m.Affix_Prefix);
        }
    }

 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          // [...]
          System.IO.TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(CsvFile, Encoding.Default);
          var csv = new CsvReader(textReader);
          csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<BreederClassMap>();
          csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
          csv.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.Default;
          csv.Read();

          var packs = csv.GetRecords<BreederTemp>().ToList();
          // Header matching [id] names exception 
        }
    }
```

Here is the CSV test file I'm using. I tried to export from XLSS to CSV-UTF8 or CSV without any changes.

```
Id;Affix;Affix_Prefix
1;(sans affixe);0
2;Des garrigues du loup de canebas;0
3;De Dan Jourdain;0
```

Did I miss something ? thanks for help

Comment: Try specifying the names manually: `Map(m => m.Id).Name("Id");`

Comment: no more luck :(

Comment: Remove  csv.Read(); and try

Comment: Removing csv.Read () solved the problem. thanks :)