# CSVHelper 7.1.1 - Header matching ['sp_ac_input_voltage_unit'] names at index 0 was not found

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am throwing this exception with trying to read from a CSV file I receive daily. I have confirmed that the column does in fact exist within the file.

The name of the column in the file is sp_ac_input_voltage-unit (note the dash), and I am trying to map this to my property named sp_ac_input_voltage_unit. The error makes me believe it is looking for a column named the above, with no dash, in which case it would not find anything.

**Class Map**

```
public sealed class ClassMap : ClassMap<SimpleProduct>
{
    public ClassMap()
    {
        AutoMap();
        Map(m => m.web_short_description).Name("web_short_description-gno");
        Map(m => m.web_long_description).Name("web_long_description-gno");
        Map(m => m.web_page_key_words).Name("web_page_key_words-gno");
        Map(m => m.web_page_description).Name("web_page_description-gno");
        Map(m => m.manual_link).Name("manual_link-gno");
        Map(m => m.web_page_title).Name("web_page_title-gno");
        Map(m => m.additional_ph).Name("additional_ph-USD");
        Map(m => m.manual_label).Name("manual_label-gno");
        Map(m => m.video_links).Name("video_links-gno");
        //Map(m => m.productSpecs);

        References<ProductSpecsMap>(m => m.productSpecs);

    }
}

public sealed class ProductSpecsMap : ClassMap<ProductSpecs>
{
    public ProductSpecsMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.sp_ac_input_voltage).Name("sp_ac_input_voltage");
        Map(m => m.sp_ac_input_voltage_unit).Name("sp_ac_input_voltage-unit");
    }
}
```

**Class map registration**

```
        using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(psm.message), new Configuration() { HasHeaderRecord = true, Delimiter = ";" }))
        {
            switch (psm.disposition)
            {
                case "GNO":
                    outputFile = Path.Combine(props.archiveDir, props.outputFile + props.suffix);
                    catalogId = "master-catalog";
                    reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ClassMap>();
                    break;
```

**Code that fails**

```
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                index++;
                var r = reader.GetRecord<SimpleProduct>(); <-- Failing on this line
```

**Edit - Adding Simple Product / Product Specs class in case that helps find solution**

```
public class SimpleProduct
{ 
other properties that are working fine

public ProductSpecs productSpecs { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSpecs
{
    public string sp_ac_input_voltage { get; set; }
    public string sp_ac_input_voltage_unit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for the GetRecords() method? Right click on GetMethod() and then select "Go To Definition".

Comment: From my reader.GetRecord line? GetRecord is part of CSV Helper. Sorry if I'm not understanding what you're asking.

Comment: Are you using latest version 7.1.1?  Does you CSV have a header row?  Does your fields have Double Quotes?  Is you separator a comma or a different character?  Can you post a couple of sample rows of you csv?   See : https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/

Comment: @jdweng Yes, using 7.1.1. CSV file does have a header row which is accounted for in the CSV config (see above code from class map registration), field does not have double quotes and should not need them, delimiter is semi-colon also accounted for in the config above. I can certainly post a couple of sample rows, but this file contains over 1200 columns.

Comment: Maybe it is the column length.  So it work with less columns?  How many characters are in the lines?  I will check the source to see if there is any limits in the input buffer.

Comment: Configuration.cs has : public virtual int BufferSize { get; set; } = 2048;  You may need to make it larger.  The code is using a TextReader and using Readline() so the terminating character may be different than the default.

Comment: @jdweng Setting a larger buffer size did not correct the issue. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: Are you using standard return character in file?

Comment: @jdweng Yes I am

Comment: Read the notes in the Configuration.cs file : names at index {headerNameIndex} was not found. Since you are using a semicolon instead of a comma I suspect the culture for you numbers uses commas.  So the failure is probably cause by your culture settings.  I will do more research.

Comment: Take a look at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582272/csvhelper-7-1-1-header-matching-id-names-at-index-0-was-not-found